# Remove word from a String in Java

Tags: java

I need to remove character from string.
the String like

```
String a="{aaaaa{bbbbbb}aaaa}";
```

How to remove {bbbbbb} from this string.

this is example string only i need to remove the string between {------}.not possible to replace

Comment: have a look at **Related Questions**

Comment: Is it always going to be a fixed `{bbbbbb}`? You could simply replace it with an empty string then

Comment: Are you looking for a pattern? May this regex help you `{[^{}]*}`. [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ns4pVljrOAUI5kw1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can do like this

```
String a="{aaaaa{bbbbbb}aaaa}";
        String target=a.copyValueOf("{bbbbbb}".toCharArray());
        a=a.replace(target, "");
```

output will be {aaaaaaaaa}

Comment: Why the unnecessary `toCharArray` and `copyValueOf`?

Comment: i thought it might be useful to use target for other purpose in the program, instead of giving directly in replace method.

Comment: Then you can just do `String target = "{bbbbbb}"`, the `String` class is immutable in Java, it is not necessary to make copies of strings.

Comment: @Jesper, watermarks may be important in such answers.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method, which *returns* a new modified `String`:

```
String a = "{aaaaa{bbbbbb}aaaa}";
a = a.replace("{bbbbbb}", "");

System.out.println(a); // {aaaaaaaaa}
```

Answer (score 2):

removes all

```
while (a.contains("{bbbbbb}")){
        a = a.replaceAll("{bbbbbb}", "");
    }
```

Comment: with more than one repetition

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "{aaaaa{bbbbbb}aaaa}";
String toRemove = "{bbbbbb}";
int x = str.indexOf(toRemove);
str = str.substring(0,x) + str.substring(x+toRemove.length(),str.length());
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I do agree with you about the link thing, but I actually don't have a link in my answer!

Comment: Apologies, I clicked the wrong feedback option. I meant to say that this may provide an answer to the question but it's good practice to include a explanation of how you came to that answer and explain your working. This will help other people understand what the code does and how it answers the question.

Comment: oh, in that case, you are probably right, I just thought it is too simple to be explained... thnx for your feedback, I'll keep that in mind :)